# Vulkan Different Push Constants in Different Shader Stages

Tags: glsl, vulkan

(I've seen similar questions but the answers didn't help me, that's why I'm asking)

I use push constant data for my vertex and tessellation evaluation shaders.

struct i declared for storing matrices:

```
struct push_constant_data {
    // vertex shader
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 model_matrix;

    // tessellation evaluation shader
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 view_matrix;
    alignas(16) glm::mat4 projection_matrix;
};
```

vertex shader:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform push_data {
    mat4 model_matrix;
} push;
```

tessellation evaluation shader:

```
layout(push_constant) uniform push_data {
    layout(offset = 64)
    mat4 view_matrix;
    mat4 projection_matrix;
} push;
```

that's how I created the ranges:

```
vk::PushConstantRange vertex_range{};
vertex_range.offset = 0;
vertex_range.size = sizeof(glm::mat4);
vertex_range.stageFlags = vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex;

vk::PushConstantRange TES_range{};
TES_range.offset = sizeof(glm::mat4);
TES_range.size = 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4);
TES_range.stageFlags = vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eTessellationEvaluation;
```

filling the struct:

```
    push_constant_data push{
        {glm::mat4(1.0f)}, //model
        {glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f))}, //view
        {glm::perspective(glm::radians(45.0f), swapchain_extent.width / (float)swapchain_extent.height, 0.1f, 10.0f)} //projection
    };
```

binding push constants:

```
    commandBuffer.pushConstants(pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4), &push);
    commandBuffer.pushConstants(pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eTessellationEvaluation, sizeof(glm::mat4), 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4), &push);
```

as a result, I see nothing. When I use

```
commandBuffer.pushConstants(
    pipeline_layout_, 
    vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex | vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eTessellationEvaluation, 
    0, 
    sizeof(push), 
    &push
);
```

I get exactly what I need, and a validation layer message of course:

> vkCmdPushConstants():
> VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT|VK_SHADER_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_BIT,
> VkPushConstantRange in VkPipelineLayout 0x9fde6b0000000014[]
> overlapping offset = 0 and size = 192, do not contain
> VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT|VK_SHADER_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_BIT.
> The Vulkan spec states: For each byte in the range specified by offset
> and size and for each shader stage in stageFlags, there must be a push
> constant range in layout that includes that byte and that stage
> (https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.3.275.0/windows/1.3-extensions/vkspec.html#VUID-vkCmdPushConstants-offset-01795)

Comment: So what is your question? You say you get exactly what you need.

Comment: Is this C++? If so, I think you should add a the C++ language tag to the question.

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED! `VkPushConstants` ' params `offset` and `size` are GPU-side ONLY.    
`std::array<glm::mat4, 2> matrices{ push.view_matrix, push.projection_matrix };
commandBuffer.pushConstants(grass_pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eTessellationEvaluation, sizeof(glm::mat4), 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4), matrices.data());` 
Note `offset` is not applied to the `push` struct, use Pointer Arithmetic instead `push + sizeof(glm::mat4)` ( as the `pValue` )

Comment: @Adriaan if I get the result I wanted and it is followed by the validation message - it's not the way to achieve it. Validation messages say that something is wrong, and these errors also affect FPS. 230 FPS with the error I mentioned vs 700 FPS without it

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it's C++ but more about Vulkan side, so language doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vkCmdPushConstants` parameters `offset` and `size` are GPU-side only.

```
commandBuffer.pushConstants(pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eVertex, 0, sizeof(glm::mat4), &push.model_matrix);

std::array<glm::mat4, 2> matrices{ push.view_matrix, push.projection_matrix };
commandBuffer.pushConstants(pipeline_layout_, vk::ShaderStageFlagBits::eTessellationEvaluation, sizeof(glm::mat4), 2 * sizeof(glm::mat4), matrices.data());
```

Note `offset` that is not applied to the `push` variable, use *Pointer Arithmetic* instead: `push + sizeof(glm::mat4)` (as the `pValue` for `vkCmdPushConstants`).